# Write a function even_numbers that uses a for loop and outputs a list that contains all the even numbers from 1 inclusive up to 2 exclusive?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

It is not working.

In [122]:

```
def even_numbers(n1, n2):
    for x in range(-2,4): 
        if (x%2 == 0):
            print(x)
```

In [123]:

Q6 Test Cases

```
assert even_numbers(-2, 4) == [-2, 0, 2]
-2
0
2
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-123-6544d23ef931> in <module>
      1 # Q6 Test Cases
----> 2 assert even_numbers(-2, 4) == [-2, 0, 2]

AssertionError:
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems in your code: first of all, `even_numbers(n1, n2)` should return the even numbers between `n1` and `n2`, however, you are always returning the even numbers between -2 and 4. Also, you are not storing the values anywhere, you are just printing them on the terminal. This is why your assertion fails. Here is a working version of your code:

```
def even_numbers(n1, n2):
    solution = []
    for x in range(n1, n2): 
        if x%2 == 0:
             solution.append(x)
    return solution
```

But instead of checking every value between n1 and n2, you can go for a nicer approach:

```
def even_numbers(n1, n2):
    if n1%2 == 0:
        return list(range(n1, n2, 2))
    else:
        return list(range(n1+1, n2, 2))
```